# django: get all columns as a list

Tags: django

This is probably very simple, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

I want to get all the columns in some rows as a list. I know I could
use values_list and flat=True and list all the columns, but is that
the only way?

I want to do something like this:

```
rows = FOO.objects.filter(bar='baz')
```

and get a list of lists instead a list of FOO objects.

Comment: It is not clear what you need, what you need is to get the list of field names? Could you please post the expected result of your query?

Comment: I want to get a list of lists, where the top level is each row, and within each of those lists, each item is a column. So for example, row[0][4] would be the fifth column in the first row.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the name of all fields this way:

```
model._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

or

```
[field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]  # for Django >= 1.9
```

therefore, you can do something like:

```
FOO.objects.filter(<your filter>).values_list( * FOO._meta.get_all_field_names(), flat=True)
```

If you don't want to pass the field names then you can do:

```
FOO.objects.values_list()
```

You can see in the [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list): "*If you don’t pass any values to values_list(), it will return all the fields in the model, in the order they were declared*"

Comment: I know how to get the column names, that is not my issue. I am looking for a way to get the rows back in a list without have to explicitly give all the column names.

Comment: Updated the response

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I did not know an empty values_list() returns all the columns.

Answer (score 10):

Modern way to do this in django >1.9:

```
[f.get_attname() for f in Restaurant._meta.fields]
```

Comment: This gets the fields that are **actually** created on the model. Using `[field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]` throws all fields associated with the model,including "related_name" associations.